# Is there a way to address the shrink / fatten / radius values of individual vertices on a curve with animation nodes?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, animation-nodes

I want to drive the fatness / thickness / radius of parts of a curve using a sound source and can't see a way to address the individual points / vertices in animation nodes...

I thought that I could possibly do it with shapekeys but they don't seem to hold that data (ie you change the radii on one shapekey and it affects all of them...)

cheers

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating the spline in Animation Nodes, you can evaluate the sound falloff and use it the the radii input in either the *Spline From Points* node or *Create From Edges* node:

[image: Radius in AN]

If you already have the curve and want to edit its radius, use the *Set Radius* node:

[image: Set Radius]